# Why does @Resource not allowed for multiple argument method

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autowired

As per [SpringReference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers) `@Resource is supported only for fields and bean property setter methods with a single argument.`

Can someone please help me getting why @Resource not supported with multiple argument method. Although looking at code for [@Autowired](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) and [@Resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/annotation/Resource.html) its similar implementation
Autwired
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR,FIELD,METHOD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)

Resource:-
@Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD})
@Retention(value=RUNTIME)

Comment: Cant help unless you post how you used @Resource in your code and what import you used.

Comment: @almasshaikh Refering to JSR-250 Resource annotation, and confusion raised actually with what Spring reference doc states.